# objectForKey: returning null

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Hi people I m working on a AlarmApp and I want to schedule some localNotifications, this works so far, but when I try to delete them my problem appears. I'm trying to list all localNotifications and loop throughout their userInfo to determinate which Notification has to be deleted. I've added a dictionary to the userInfo property of the Notification with value = index of alarm im alarmArray and key = "index" and now I'm trying to get backt that index with objectForKey: I've also tried valueForKey: but it doesn't work. When I log the dictionary it said that the dictionary contains one item: { 0 = index; } but when I try to log the valueForKey:@"index" the console gives me back a "null".

So can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
- (void)deleteNotificationForKey:(int)key
{
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *eventArray = [application scheduledLocalNotifications];
    for (int i = 0; i < eventArray.count; i++) {
        UILocalNotification* notification = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSDictionary *currentUserInfo = notification.userInfo;
        NSString *index = [currentUserInfo objectForKey:@"index"];
        NSLog(@"%s:%@",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,currentUserInfo);
        NSLog(@"%s:%@",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,index);
        NSLog(@"%s:%d",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,key);
        if ([index intValue] == key)
        {
            NSLog(@"%s:%@",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,notification);
            [application cancelLocalNotification:notification];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The key is "0" and the value is "index".

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you use `stringWithFormat`:

```
NSString *index = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [currentUserInfo valueForKey:@"index"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation your dictionary object is @"index" and key is @0, if you try this, it should work

`NSString *index = [currentUserInfo objectForKey:@0];`

To solve this problem you need to change @0 and @"index" places when you initialize your dictionary

Comment: Thanks i changed the dictionarys key and value and it worked well